# Find average rate of change in 3 dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Problem 10:]

At first I thought this would be equivalent to the directional derivative, but it seems that it isn't. I've tried manipulating the average rate of change formula to suit this question but no luck so far. I'm down to my last attempt so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Instead of uploading a picture, use mathjax : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For average rate of change you just compute the value of the function at each endpoint. You take the difference between those values and divide by the distance between the two points.

Answer (score 0):

Might be
$$
\frac{1}{\lVert b - a \rVert}\int\limits_a^b f(u)  \cdot du
$$
for the average change, where $a = (6,1)$ and $b=(7,2)$. And
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial n} = \left. (\grad f) \right\vert_a \cdot n \\
n = \frac{b - a}{\lVert b - a \rVert}
$$
for the instantaneous derivative in direction $n$.